# Check if database exist

Tags: bash, mongodb

How do I check if a database exists in bash?

I'm planning to make an automated backup script, where each website's db name is:

```
(siteName) mysite.com  = mysite_com (dbName)
```

Comment: why did u vote to close?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if a file exists with the -e bash command. MongoDB creates a Namespace file for each database, so search for those. Something like

```
if [ -e /data/db/$DBNAME.ns ]; then
  `mongodump -d $DBNAME --out /backup/directory`
fi
```

Assuming your data is stored in /data/db

Have a look at the mongodump command which can be used to backup data from your mongo db instance
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Backups

Comment: Upvoted! The back-up documentation has moved to [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backups/) and remember that `mongodump` doesn't dump the indexes. Read the afore-mentioned extensive back-up documentation for other ideas.